# How to get started with OpenFOAM for CFD

Tags: fluid-dynamics, openfoam

I'm looking at using OpenFOAM for solving basic internal flows in CFD. What is the best way to get started, and could anyone please point me to a good online reference to go to with any questions I might have once I dive in? I've heard that it is quite niche as of now and many solver functions are not that well documented. Obviously the documentation that comes with the package itself is a start but is there a third-party reference (something like an OpenFOAM wiki)?

Comment: OpenFOAM is a good software, but it takes some time to learn well.  Have you looked at the tutorial problems provided with the package?

Comment: On Area 51 of StackExchange a site specific to [OpenFOAM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88229/openfoam-technology) is currently proposed.
Please, support the site to get it online.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For running of  CFD simulations, I would suggest to start with the UserGuide and ProgrammersGuide. The ProgrammersGuide document features case examples as well, and it explains additional stuff such as boundary conditions. Using OpenFOAM on the top level is fairly easy, once you get a hang of the configuration files. Both documents are available in the */doc* directory. Once you are done with this, you can find a lot of additional material from the Chalmers university: [Chalmers OpenFOAM course](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD/) organized by prof. Håkan Nilsson.

When you are done with this, dig through the [Wiki](http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page). Concentrate on the task you want to accomplish: the library is *huge* so there is no chance in getting to know it if you have a wide approach to learning how it operates. Work on specific problems, try to find documentation, engage in discussions on the forum and the extend project (see below).

If you are interested in a specific problem, try to find out which solver is used to simulate this, e.g. for turbulent/laminar stationary solution, use *simpleFoam*, for transiert laminar solution, use *icoFoam*, etc. All of the solvers are saved in a directory structure that corresponds to their use like */multiphase/incompressible/les/interFoam* would be a vof-like solver used for two phase Large Eddy Simulations (les).

Start with running the cases from the tutorial directories. Always make a copy of the simulation case, so you can have the original (if you use git, and make a mistake, checkout the directory to revert to its original state).

If you have made a successful instalation of OpenFOAM on your machine, execute *alias* on the comnand line and see that there are some nifty commands that help you get started:

- *tut* brings you to the tutorial directories
- *run* brings you to the run directory: this is where you run your simulations
- *sol* brings you to the directories of the solvers

...

You can ask questions on the [OpenFOAM Forum](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/) when you run into a problem, and there is a directory of PhD and MSc theses and articles on OpenFOAM available at the FAMENA (Faculty of Mechanical Engineering, Uni. Zagreb, Croatia) [File Server](http://powerlab.fsb.hr/ped/kturbo/OpenFOAM/).

[OpenFOAM Summer School](http://www.fsb.unizg.hr/?OpenFOAM_Summer_School_2012) is a really cool course organized by prof. Hrvoje Jasak at FAMENA, it takes place sometime in September each year, and it's a great opportunity to learn and get to know researchers working with OF.

Also, there is a site organized by the OpenFOAM community: [OpenFOAM extend project](http://www.extend-project.de/), where you can engage into discussion with people as well.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is a wiki for openfoam: http://openfoamwiki.net It is a helpful site for openfoam in general yet the tutorials are not enough. Starting point should always be the manuals of openfoam. I started with the pdf's provided by the package around five years ago and I found them pretty handy. Real community of openfoam can be found in [here](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/).

Comment: erhanturan, welcome to scicomp! Could you elaborate on what in the manuals is helpful for newcomers to OpenFOAM?

Comment: Tutorials in UserGuide.pdf are useful for newbies. Files are located [here](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/tree/master/doc/Guides-a4).

Answer (score 4):

You can get a lot of help from http://www.cfd-online.com/. It's a good forum with a lot of active members working on OpenFoam.

Answer (score 1):

[The Foam House](http://the-foam-house5.webnode.es/) is an excellent website for beginners. Several problems of varying degree of complexity are introduced in step by step manner.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I also started from the basic and have capture all my experiences, problems etc in the two links:
http://www.cfdyna.com/Home/OpenFOAM.html
&
http://www.cfdyna.com/Home/OpenFOAM_Tut.pdf

Hope this helps! Please let me know your comments and I will try to make it better.

Regards,

Answer (score -3):

we are working to open a CFD academy with a CFD starting Courses Free
http://cadcae.net
for example you can see a specific training like [curso-cfd-openfoam](http://cadcae.net/training/curso-cfd-openfoam)
Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: This may not address the original request for "a good online reference to go with any questions" since training materials are often organized in a manner less comprehensive than documentation.  You are a new user at this point and lack the reputation needed to Comment, but keep in mind the distinction between Answers and Comments if you plan to stick around.

Comment: I also think this constitutes self-promotion [which tends to be frowned upon in the Stack Exchange network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion). Given that no free alternatives are listed, and the "resource" posted is in fact a product costing a few hundred euro, I'm inclined to delete this post for violating site policy unless it is revised.